# flask html jinja dont display none when appending to list

Tags: python, html, flask, web-scraping, jinja2

I have a python script that scrapes some pages for movies in different theaters and displays the result in a html page using flask. I pass a list from my python script that holds at least 1 element (name of the theater) and iterate over the rest of the list (todays movies) and print it.

In the html I want to check the length of this list. If list = 1 I want to print a text saying nothing is available. This is my html code

```
<div class="theater">
      <div class="row_header">
        {{ my_theater[0] }}
      </div>
      <div class="row_sub_header">
        Opening at 11am
      </div>
      {% if my_theater|length == 1 %} {{ my_theater.append("No movies available today") }} {% endif %} {% for m in my_theater[1:] %} 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
        {{ m }} 
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <div class="row_sub_header2">
        <p>Price: 10 USD</p>
      </div>      
</div>
```

[And this is the html output (screenshot):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEZVt.png)

How come "none" is displayed in the html and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes much easier if you pass `my_theater` (as a single value) and `my_movies` (as a list that might be empty) separately. Minus markup, the Jinja2 part would then look like

```
{{ my_theater }}

{% for movie in my_movies %}
    {{ movie }}
{% else %}
    No movies available today
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{ my_theater.append('x') or ""}}
```